# Интерполяция на CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, шейдеры

Есть ли в CUDA функционал для автоматической интерполяции значений подобно тому, как это происходит в вершинном шейдере? Тобишь, к примеру, у меня есть некоторый набор 2D вершин, разбитых по треугольникам, в которых имеются некоторые значения, которые нужно проинтерполировать между собой. В OpenGL это делается простейшим образом с помощью вершинного шейдера, но в CUDA для решения этой задачи мне пришлось делать это вручную (обрезать треугольники выходящие за пределы обрасти, разбивать треугольники на верхний и нижний, линейно интерполировать по сторонам треугольников а потом уже интерполировать по строкам между сторонами). Может в CUDA есть втроенный функционал для этого?

Comment: Сделал корректную капитализацию и убрал выделение кодом - это же не фрагменты кода, не имена переменных.

Comment: Куда предназначена для общих вычислений и не является заменой графического конвейера.